# Como fazer Scrapping de uma página que tem um javascript's usando python ?

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler, web-scraping, scraping

Eu preciso fazer scrapping de uma página, porém na entrada da page tem um botão (aparentemente um Javascript) que dá acesso à todo conteúdo da pagina em si. 
Usando as libs tradicionais(urllib2, requests, BeatifulSoap) não consigo "puxar" o conteúdo que preciso, alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Poste o código que tentou fazer sem sucesso e, de preferência, o código JavaScript que impede a conexão direto com a página.

Comment: Precisa ser somente em python?

Comment: Para puxar dados de páginas com JS você deve utilizar uma biblioteca como o [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) ou o [Dryscrape](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). O primeiro já utilizei e recomendo, já o dryscrape, ainda não utilizei, mas já li coisas boas a respeito. Outro ponto, ao perguntar algo relacionado a web-scraping, poste o link que está acessando... ajuda bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo usar o selenium para fazer webscrapping em sites que tem muito javascript. Normalmente, utilizo o Selenium com Java, mas em Python funciona também. Abaixo, um código com um exemplo bobo, mas funcional.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Lembre-se que, para utilizar o Driver do Chrome, é necessário ter o Chromedriver, que você pode baixar em [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). A documentação do Selenium WebDriver em Python está em [Documentação](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Comment: Vale galera, consegui!